# How to get the build for a given commit / revision from the web interface in Buildbot?

Tags: gdb, buildbot

E.g., on the GDB Buildbot instance http://gdb-build.sergiodj.net, I want to check the builds for git commit `68b975af7ef47a9d28f21f4c93431f35777a5109` , Git tag `binutils-2_25`, which happened in Dec 2014 to compare with my local results.

Is that possible?

Things which complicate that feature:

- there may be multiple builds per commit, e.g. different platforms. OK, give me a list of all of them.
- some commits don't have builds.

  That buildbot seems configured to run only every few commits to save CPU.

  In that case, I would like to see the nearest built parent on my search result.

There has also been some discussion for this on Google Groups for Chromium, but I couldn't find a good solution: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/infra-dev/T_7S9HXLWlo

I have also opened a feature request at: http://trac.buildbot.net/ticket/3320

For GDB in particular, I know about the `gdb-testers` mailing list https://sourceware.org/ml/gdb-testers/ , which seems to get daily automated emails from Buildbot. I'm not very satisfied with it because there is not one email per build (there is more than one daily build), but searching that list is a possible workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides the automated email results, GDB maintainers have also set up one Git repository per test environment that contains one commit for every build under a cgit web interface at http://gdb-build.sergiodj.net/cgit

For example, for Debian x86_64, you can clone it with:

```
git clone http://gdb-build.sergiodj.net/git/Debian-x86_64-m64/.git
```

Each commit contains the `gdb.sum` and `gdb.log`, which are the main outputs of DejaGnu's tests.

Note however that those repositories are pretty big, 350M currently, and take a long time to clone.

The Buildbot configuration for the Git and email outputs seems to be on the personal Git server of the responsible developer: http://git.sergiodj.net/?p=gdb-buildbot.git;a=summary as mentioned on the ml announcement: https://sourceware.org/ml/gdb/2015-01/msg00043.html